# Why does the Catholic Church legislate a minimum age for receiving Holy Orders?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments, holy-orders

Why does the Catholic Church legislate a minimum age for receiving Holy Orders?

Comment: Hello Thom.  This is a good question, but it was a little sparse and unclear.  When asking in the future, adding links and descriptions to help explain your questions is very helpful.  Additionally, a brief explanation of why you're asking (if it's not too personal) also helps guide us to the best answer for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Canonical age](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32295) for Holy Orders

[1983 can. 1031 §1](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3Q.HTM) (=[1917 can. 975 §1](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=PA338)) says one must be at least 25 to be ordained [licitly](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34594) (legally):

> The presbyterate [priesthood] is not to be conferred except on those who have completed the twenty-fifth year of age and possess sufficient maturity

[Validity](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=37033) requires a baptized male, [1983 can. 1024](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3P.HTM) (=[1917 can. 968](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XbtF6Y21LUC&pg=PA336)), so technically a baptized male baby could be validly ordained a priest, but doing so would break canon law.

## Church's authority to legislate canonical age

Just as the Church has the authority to establish [impediments](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34115) to contracting marriage (cf. [Council of Trent session 24 can. 3](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.xi.html#v.i.i.xi-p4.33) & [4](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.xi.html#v.i.i.xi-p4.39)), so, too, can she legislate the canonical age for receiving Holy Orders.

## Holy Orders and Matrimony are for the common good.

The Church has this legislative authority because Matrimony and Holy Orders are the two sacraments "intended for the perfection of the multitude", not primarily "for the perfection of the individual"; Holy Orders remedies "divisions in the community", and matrimony remedies "the decrease in the population that results from death" ([*Summa Theologica* III q. 65 a. 2 co.](https://isidore.co/forum/index.php?topic=131.msg356#top_subject)).

Comment: I have read can. 1024 both in English and in German language: As far as I understand this rule correctly, it *only* says that that sacrament is *always invalid* if it is given to a non-baptized or a female person. The rule does not say that it is valid in all other cases.

Comment: Except that, as a principle dating back at least to 1298 with *Regula Juris,* permissions in Canon Law are to be interpreted as widely as possible and prohibitions as narrowly as possible. Both of those principles lead Canon 1024 to mean that *any* baptised male is validly ordained; but there are impediments to a valid ordination (which need to be narrowly applied) listed in Canons 1040-1044. How a *neophyte* in Canon 1042(3) is defined might become important in the case of a baby — or a new convert over the age of 25 for whom ordination would otherwise be licit.

Answer (score 2):

Holy Orders is a call to a specific role in the church. The role includes providing spiritual counsel, church leadership, presiding at Mass, instructing the faithful, hearing confession. None of these can be done by a baby.

Not all Catholics are called to be priests. Even the most faithful and devout may be called to some other role. Deciding if someone is called to be a priest cannot be done while they are still a baby.

Being a priest requires knowledge and training, and people do not receive Holy Orders until the training is complete. If someone were ordained as a baby, even when they grew to adulthood but before they were trained they would technically be permitted to carry out all the above roles but would not have the ability to carry them out effectively.